# jquery to change td2 value where td1 match

Tags: jquery

I want to change td2 value where td1 match. For example I have column macaddress and renewalstatus. I want to set Renewal status=Requested where macid is 54564564654A through jquery

```
MAC Address     Renewal Status
54564564654A    Renewal Due
545645646546    Renewal Due
```

I have code that change match value but not other td

```
$("td:contains('54564564654A')").text("Value 1.TO-THE-MAX");
```

Above code change 54564564654A to Value 1.TO-THE-MAX. But I want to change Renewal status to Requested. Where macid match.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your actual HTML here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get to the parent `tr` using `closest()` and then find the second column using the `nth-child(2)` selector on `td`

```
$("td:contains('54564564654A')").closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text("Requested");
```